# Is there a way to order SQLite SELECT result values by condition order?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, conditional-statements, where-clause

I'm trying to retrieve values from a local SQLite database. The entries of the table ordered by 'itemnumber ASC'.

When querying with multiple conditions, I want the selected entries to be ordered by the sequence of my where conditions.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `Articles` 
(
    `Itemnumber`    TEXT,
    `Description`   TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sellingprice_` REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Itemnumber`)
);

INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ('00000015', 'Lorem ipsum', 15.99);
INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ('00000016', 'Lorem ipsum', 16.99);
INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ('00000018', 'Lorem ipsum', 18.99);
INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ('00000019', 'Lorem ipsum', 19.99);
INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ('00000021', 'Lorem ipsum', 21.99);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Articles 
WHERE Itemnumber LIKE '00000021'
   OR Itemnumber Like '00000015'
   OR Itemnumber Like '00000018';
```

Result:

```
[ITEMNUMBER]    [DESCRIPTION]    [SELLINGPRICE]
  00000015       Lorem ipsum         15.99
  00000018       Lorem ipsum         18.99
  00000021       Lorem ipsum         21.99
```

But it needs to be like:

```
[ITEMNUMBER]    [DESCRIPTION]    [SELLINGPRICE]
  00000021       Lorem ipsum         21.99
  00000015       Lorem ipsum         15.99
  00000018       Lorem ipsum         18.99
```

Comment: Please provide demo content of your database by adding a few lines of `insert ...`. Well done providing the database structure as `create table ...` by the way. It is the easiest and most helpful kind of a [mcve], yet so few users bother to provide it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity concerning an aside oddity. Why do you use `like` without any wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `order by` like this:

```
order by 
  case Itemnumber 
    when '00000021' then 0
    when '00000015' then 1
    when '00000018' then 2
  end;
```

Comment: This will probably be very complicated when you are selecting a few hundreds rows like this

Comment: I hope you are not trying to sort *a few hundreds rows like this*. Are you?

Comment: The table contains some million articles and I need to get the data via C# from that table for specific itemnumbers. This can be only one itemnumber but maybe also some hundreds.

Comment: And is there any logic for which numbers you apply these conditions? If yes then post it. If not then how do you expect to achieve this sorting?

Comment: No there's no order for the selected itemnumbers.
Imaging you want to get the prices for every article on an order. I want to get the prices in the same sorting as on the order. So they don't mix up. Order in sense of booking.

Comment: *I want to get the prices in the same sorting as on the order* this means that you want to join rows from 2 tables. In your question you don't mention 2 tables. Also the rows of a table are not stored sorted in a certain order. You can sort them by applying special conditions in an `order by` clause.

Comment: I only have one table. It's sorted because it gets imported by another software which  inserts the values sorted alphabetically.
I'm writing a C# software which reads any amount of itemnumbers and prints/exports the prices from the table above.

Comment: I suppose you need different ordering than alphabetical, right? Do you know what this order is like in advance?

Comment: It should be the same order as my itemnumbers I put into the Select Statement.

Comment: If you mean as you have them in the where part of your question then there is not another way than the case statement. The only thing that you can improve is to use this in where: `WHERE Itemnumber IN ('00000021', '00000015', '00000018',...)`